# Query firebase to return if value more than number

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from Firebase.

This is more or less my data structure:

```
"Reports" : {
    "N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2" : 2,
    "eLLfNlWLkTcImTRqrYnU0nWuu9P2" : 2
},
"Users":{
    "N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2" : {
        "completedWorks" : {
            ...
        },
        "reports" : {
            "-LHs0yxUXn-TQC7z_MJM" : {
                "category" : "Niewyraźne zdjęcie",
                "creatorID" : "z8DxcXyehgMhRyMqmf6q8LpCYfs1",
                "reportedID" : "N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2",
                "resolved" : false,
                "text" : "heh",
                "workID" : "-LHs-aZJkAhEf1RHVasg"
            },
            "-LHs1hzlL4roUJfMlvyA" : {
                "category" : "Zdjęcie nie przedstawia zadania",
                "creatorID" : "z8DxcXyehgMhRyMqmf6q8LpCYfs1",
                "reportedID" : "N06Jrz5hx6Q9bcVDBBUrF3GKSTp2",
                "resolved" : false,
                "text" : "",
                "workID" : "-LHs-aZJkAhEf1RHVasg"
            }
        },
        "userType" : "company",
        "verified" : true
    },
}
```

So as you can see the number of reports is listed in the `Reports` part. How can I make Firebase return only the ids of the users where the report number is over or equal 3?

Something like this (this will not work, but I hope kind of shows what I was thinking about):

```
firebase.database().ref('Reports').orderBy(whatHere?).moreThen(2).on('value', snap => {
```

Is this even doable like this? If yes how could I do it? I want to grab the IDs of the users where reports are >= 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `orderByValue()`:

```
firebase.database().ref('Reports').orderByValue().startAt(3).on('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(reportSnapshot => {
    console.log(reportSnapshot.key);
  })
})
```

Also check out the [Firebase documentation on ordering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for doing that but not exactly the way you wants. You have to use javascript for further processing. One is to use `limitToLast` after using order by. which will give the last numbers from the result.

```
firebase.database().ref('Reports').orderBy(reportid).limitToLast(2).on('value', snap => {
```

Or use `startAt` and `endAt` to skip and fetch the result as `offset` which can provide the data between two reportId.

```
firebase.database().ref('Reports').orderBy(reportid).
          .startAt(reportIdStart)
          .endAt(reportIdLast)
          .limitToLast(15)
```

According [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data):

> Using startAt(), endAt(), and equalTo() allows you to choose arbitrary
>   starting and ending points for your queries

To filter data, you can combine any of the limit or range methods with an order-by method when constructing a query.

> Unlike the order-by methods, you can combine multiple limit or range
>   functions. For example, you can combine the startAt() and endAt()
>   methods to limit the results to a specified range of values.

For more information go through documentation on [filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

Comment: So this will only limit the amount of returned objects right?

Comment: @AlexIronside yes then you can use javascript toprocess the result. Because this is the only way firebase proivides to fetch the result for limiting the records.

Comment: @AlexIronside there is no direct way to get that value greater than or less than a number. I have faced the issue myself many a times. So order the result in asc order and get the values which are greater that certain number